# Clion компилятор

Tags: c++, intellij-idea, clion

Установил себе *clion*, но скомпилировать ничего не могу даже стандартный `helloworld`
Получаю ошибку:

> Error:Neither MinGW nor Cygwin is selected

Понимаю, что чего не хватает, а чего именно не пойму (да и в гугле ничего не ясно).
Пытался переменные среды создавать, ничего не помогло.
Как решить проблему ?

Answer (score 1):

Так тут же прямым текстом написано, что для сборки проекта вам нужно выбрать MinGW и(или) Cygwin. В настройках проекта у вас вообще выбран MinGW?

Comment: Так где его выбрать, где именно находиться он ?

Comment: Компилятор или настройки?

Comment: Компилятор надо отдельно скачивать или где он по стандарту в паке лежит

Comment: @user206902 Так, из вашего вопроса понимаю, что в настройках среды вы еще не копались. Если при установке Clion не было выбора установки MinGW или Cygwin, значит нужно их подтягивать отдельно. Хорошая инструкция есть [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190121/cant-install-mingw-for-clion).